# Child process spawn: Unknown system errno 740

Tags: node.js

If I execute just this one line:

`require('child_process').spawn('C:\\Users\\me\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\1131128-16232-bid56z__some_installer.exe').on('close', function (code) { });`

Then I get an exception:

`Error: spawn Unknown system errno 740`

I'm at a loss. Can someone help me shed some light on this?

Answer (score 2):

On Windows, error [740 (`ERROR_ELEVATION_REQUIRED`)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681388%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#ERROR_ELEVATION_REQUIRED) means that the software needs to run as administrator. Run it with [`runas`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771525.aspx).

Comment: Thanks. Knowing what the error means is a huge help. And the "runas" certainly seems like a solution in the right direction. Though, I might be using it incorrectly, and I haven't been able to get it working yet. If I do...

`require('child_process').spawn('runas', ['/user:my_machine_name\\administrator', 'C:\\Users\\me\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\1131130-18300-1wol3cr__some_installer.exe']);` ...I don't get any error, but the external program doesn't appear to run either.